# Formatting Time Stamps

Tags: r

I am trying to correct and reformat Timestamps in a 24 hour format, however they are missing enough numbers to use the POSIXct function correctly.

Here is an example of the Date and Timestamps. Within the data frame their is a column for Year (ex:2018), DOY-day of year (ex:305), and TIME (ex: 0).

The TIME column is giving me issues. The values look like (0, 30, 100, 130, 200). In this case 0 should be 00:00:00 if formatted to a %H:%M:%S format. My issue is I need to figure out how to format it that way.

Here is the code I tried:

```
mt$date <- as.POSIXct(paste(mt$Year, mt$DOY, mt$Time), format = "%Y %j %H")
```

Thanks for any help, I am sure this is likely an easy fix.

Comment: @akrun ```30, should be 00:30:00```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could make use of `sprintf` to create the `format`

```
mt$date <- with(mt, as.POSIXct(paste0(Year, '-', DOY,' ', 
 sub('^(..)', '\\1:', sprintf('%04d', Time))), format = "%Y-%j %H:%M"))
mt$date
#[1] "2018-11-01 00:00:00 EDT" "2018-11-08 00:30:00 EST" "2018-06-24 01:00:00 EDT"
#[4] "2018-08-13 01:30:00 EDT" "2018-11-16 10:00:00 EST"
```

#### data

```
mt <- structure(list(Year = c(2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018), DOY = c(305, 
312, 175, 225, 320), Time = c(0, 30, 100, 130, 1000)),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: Very close it works for ```0, to 930, and formats as 00:00:00 and 09:30:00``` but breaks at ```1000 and outputs 01:00:00```

Comment: @Alex please check my updated.  It is shoowing `10:00:00`

Comment: Thank you, totally correct, I really appreciate the response